# Are abstract base classes appropriate if I neither use `@abstractmethod` nor `register`

Tags: python

I have two unrelated classes that both share a certain behaviour. Is it appropriate to use a common abstract base class for the two classes, even if a simple base class would achieve the same thing. I will never use `register` nor does my abstract base class use `@abstractmethod`.

The only reason I would derive the base class from ABCMeta is to document that this class should never be instantiated directly. (It can, however be instantiated, because it has no abstract methods)

Comment: Why not have it be a concrete class that the others contain, rather than inherit?

Comment: Because it inherits from `str` and I like `isinstance(a, str)` to return True.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, inheriting from mixin-like classes is an okay-ish approach since the language supports multiple inheritance. The only caveat is the `__init__()` method: all classes that you inherit from must have compatible constructors since their order is not known at class definition time.

In practice, using inheritance is usually not appropriate since delegation can achieve the same thing with far less headache. So instead of

```
class Mixin(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__x = x

  def method(self):
    ...

class A(Mixin):
  def __init__(self, x):
    super().__init__(x)

  ...

class B(Mixin):
  def __init__(self, x):
    super().__init__(x)

  ...
```

We might say

```
class Mixin(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__x = x

  def method(self):
    ...

class A(Mixin):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__mixin = Mixin(x)

  def method(self):
    return self.__mixin.method()

  ...

class B(Mixin):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.__mixin = Mixin(x)

  def method(self):
    return self.__mixin.method()

  ...
```

(The disadvantage of manual delegation is that the docstrings get lost, but preventing that reliably is a bit non-trivial due to the finer intricacies of Python's object member resolution protocol.)

If the mixin has neither multiple public methods nor any associated data, a free function instead of a mixin class is preferable:

```
def common_method(self):
  ...

class A(Mixin):
  def method(self):
    return common_method()

  ...

class B(Mixin):
  def method(self):
    return common_method()

  ...
```

Delegation is only inappropriate in case you need to perform `isinstance(o, Mixin)` checks. In most cases this is a design flaw and can be avoided, especially if the code performing that check is under your control. Otherwise, the object adapter pattern may be suitable, which is basically the same as the delegation example but flipped around:

```
class RequiredType(object):
  ...

class ActualType(object):
  ...

class Adapter(RequiredType):
  def __init__(self, target):
    self.__target = target

  def method_of_required_type(self):
     return self.__target.method_of_actual_type()
```

Now given a function `needs_required_type(...)`, given an instance of the actual type you could call it as `needs_required_type(Adapter(instance))`. This is usually far preferable to inheriting the required type into the actual type, since inheritance possibly exposes a lot of undesirable methods and fields. This is especially bad for built-in types like `str` or `list`. I've seen cases that rendered an API absolutely incomprehensible because one class inherited from `list` as an implementation detail, which basically ruined any pretence of encapsulation.